# spring-cloud with Feign/Ribbon/Eureka - unable to discover service instances

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-feign

My feign client currently fails to discover service instances using Eureka. My configuration includes the following annotations:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@FeignClientScan
```

I included the following dependencies (spring-cloud 1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT):

```
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka
com.netflix.feign:feign-core
com.netflix.feign:feign-ribbon
```

As far as I can tell, the feign client makes use of a `ConfigurationBasedServerList` and therefore requires the addresses of the available service instances to be explicitly specified in the configuration file (`ribbon.serverList` property).

However, everything is working fine if I explicitly specify:

```
ribbon.NIWSServerListClassName: com.netflix.niws.loadbalancer.DiscoveryEnabledNIWSServerList
```

My test application also makes use of a Spring RestTemplate based client automatically configured to make use of an Eureka-enabled Ribbon implementation. Strange thing is that the Feign client is working fine (i.e. finds service instances) if the RestTemplate is invoked first. Looks like the RestTemplate setup performs some (static) initialisations somewhere that then benefit to the feign client.

Do I miss something in how Feign support should be configured?

Comment: Where's your `@FeignClient` declaration?

Comment: also what does `/autoconfig` show?  There's a possibility that something didn't get auto-configured.

Comment: The `@FeignClient` annotation is declared on the java interface representing the remote service (it also specifies the serviceId).

As for what reports /autoconfig - hard to tell if something is wrong since I have no clue of what should actually be activated. A copy of the output is available here: http://pastebin.com/a2iVuUDp

Comment: `NIWSServerListClassName` should be set for you.  I can't see anything obvious in `/autoconfig` that is missing.  Any chance you could share a project that recreates the problem?

Comment: I have created a sample project to illustrate the case. It is available at [link](https://github.com/brenuart/spring-boot-pastebin.git) - in the feign subdirectory. Please see the README.txt for usage information. Hope you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Nobody listening anymore ?

Comment: @brenuart, I was unable to reproduce the problem using your project.  Maybe updates to `spring-cloud-netflix` have overcome the issue?  Are you still experiencing the problem?

Comment: There is now an example here: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/feign-eureka